# What does 'Total: 418 (kernel 35238)' mean in `ss -s` output?

Tags: nat

I'm investigating why sometimes I can't connect to some random machines/ports outside of my server (which has hypervisor with NAT for guests) network.

What does `Total: 418 (kernel 35238)` here means? Doesn't look normal at all. Is there a list of these "connections" where I can check them one by one?

```
root@s1:~# ss -s
Total: 418 (kernel 35238)
TCP:   49 (estab 4, closed 32, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 32/0), ports 0

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         35238     -         -
RAW       0         0         0
UDP       8         5         3
TCP       17        12        5
INET      25        17        8
FRAG      0         0         0

root@s1:~# conntrack -L | wc -l
2402
root@s1:~# netstat -a | wc -l
317
```

Thanks.